# Display sum of a column from a table in OpenCart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I'm working in OpenCart, and I am not used to MVC or PHP . I'm trying to get the sum of a column from a table and display it in a template file. I'm having a hard time setting it up. I don't get how to set the control
I think I've set up the model correct.
Model:

```
    // sum of all rows in a column(amount) from a table
public function getSum() {
   $amount_total = $this->db->query(‘SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM table’);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($amount_total);
$sum= $row[‘amount_sum’];

return $sum; 
}
```

Control:

```
$total_amount = $this->model_order->getSum();
$this->data['amount_total'] = array(got lost here, maybe not an array?);
//not sure how to finish control
//not sure how to pass to view
```

View://in the tpl file do I just do a php statement like this?:

```
<?php echo $amount_total; ?>
```

Any help would be great, I've been trying different things I find on here and and other places as well but Im just getting more confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using MVC of the opencart then how you can use model in your script.

But if you are using the model any how then you need to replace these lines  as

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($amount_total);
$sum= $row[‘amount_sum’];

to

$sum=$amount_total->row[‘amount_sum’];

I hope it will work for you.